# Connecting python with Hortonworks Data Platform sandbox

Tags: python, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to use pyhive/phys2 library. I installed pyhive, but when I use it in a program I get an `Import error:No sasl module found`. So I pip installed sasl. Then I am getting:

```
sasl/saslwrapper.cpp(247) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Users\Imdad\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I tried finding a solution but nothing is helping.
I am using Python 2.7 and HDP 2.5 sandbox on Windows 10.

Any help?

Answer (score -2):

I tried the last solution mentioned in this discussion. Hopefully this helps you too!!
[Hadoop: Python client driver for HiveServer2 fails to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838752/hadoop-python-client-driver-for-hiveserver2-fails-to-install)

> If you have an error in Windows when installing "sasl" with
>
> pip install sasl
>
> you can install pre-compiled packet.
>
> Download sasl packet for python36 in x64 from link:
>   https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl
>
> Then run pip install sasl-0.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)