# How can i install pyhs2 in linux environment?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip

## Approach

I use :

```
sudo pip3 install pyhs2
```

but it’s not working.

## Problem

It show this error like as picture.

[image]

## Question

In this situation how can i install "pyhs2" library in my linux environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838752/hadoop-python-client-driver-for-hiveserver2-fails-to-install , why don't you look into this answer, might help you fix your problem

Comment: i all ready try it like 'sudo pip3 install pyhs2' or 'pip install pyhs2' like that but same result not working, at lase it show this error as picture. Sorry your ans is not help me. Please give me different idea. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the actual text, properly formatted.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There's a clear error in the output that you've shown:

```
fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory.
```

This error occurs when the install process is trying to compile some C code.  The error is telling you that your system is missing some C header files (and probably the corresponding libraries).  On a Red Hat-style system (Red Hat, CentOS, Fedora, etc), you would need to run:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
```

On a Debian-style system (Debian, Ubuntu), you would need to run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```